# Interview: Find the whole cubes between range of two Integers

Tags: java

I just gave a coding interview on codility

I was asked the to implement the following, but i was not able to finish it in 20 minutes, now I am here to get ideas form this community

Write a function `public int whole_cubes_count ( int A,int B )` where it should return whole cubes within the range

For example if A=8 and B=65, all the possible cubes in the range are 2^3 =8 , 3^3 =27 and 4^3=64, so the function should return  count 3

I was not able to figure out how to identify a number as whole cube.  How do I solve this problem?

A and B can have range from [-20000 to 20000]

This is what I tried

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Solution1 {
  public int whole_cubes_count ( int A,int B ) {
      int count =0;

    while(A<=B)
    {
        double v = Math.pow(A, 1 / 3); // << What goes here?
        System.out.println(v);
        if (v<=B)
            {
            count=count+1;
            }
        A =A +1;
    }
    return count ;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    System.out.println("Enter 1st Number");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int s1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter 2nd Number");
    //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int s2 = scan.nextInt();
    Solution1 n = new Solution1();
     System.out.println(n.whole_cubes_count (s1,s2));
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I solve this problem is my question, I am posting my code now, Thanks

Comment: Please indent lines of code with four spaces.

Comment: Thank you for indenting lines of code with two spaces.

Comment: @ErickRobertson Well, I was referring to the display formatting, not the formatting within the code itself.

Comment: Tell the prospective employer that `public int whole_cubes_count ( int A,int B )` doesn't follow the accepted Java style guidelines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Down and dirty, that's what I say.**

If you only have 20 minutes, then they shouldn't expect super-optimized code.  So don't even try.  Play to the constraints of the system which say only +20,000 to -20,000 as the range.  You know the cube values have to be within 27, since 27 * 27 * 27 = 19683.

```
public int whole_cubes_count(int a, int b) {
    int count = 0;
    int cube;
    for (int x = -27; x <= 27; x++) {
        cube = x * x * x;
        if ((cube >= a) && (cube <= b))
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, they gave me range for and B

Comment: You only need to loop from -27 to 27. (27^3 = 19683)

Comment: When there's only 55 possible cubes, and you only have to cube a number, there isn't a risk of the algorithm taking too long.

Comment: Yea your right, but that's an easy change and might as well have been done. Anyway, you have my +1.

Comment: @A.R.S. I used your numbers :)

Comment: It's sad that one-off answers can get so many votes and more useful answers don't get many ;-(

Comment: @Code-Guru sorry i was looking for more complete answer!

Comment: @SuperMan Besides, I intentionally gave an incomplete answer so that you can exercise your programming muscles by filling in the details.

Answer (score 7):

For the positive cubes:

```
i = 1
while i^3 < max
    ++i
```

Similarly for the negative cubes but with an absolute value in the comparison.

To make this more general, you need to find the value of `i` where `i^3 >= min`, in the case that both `min` and `max` are positive. A similar solution works if both `min` and `max` are negative.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it can be computed with O(1) complexity, we will need to find the largest cube that fits into the range, and the smallest one. All those that are between will obviously also be inside.

```
def n_cubes(A, B):
    a_cr = int(math.ceil(cube_root(A)))
    b_cr = int(math.floor(cube_root(B)))

    if b_cr >= a_cr:
        return b_cr - a_cr + 1
    return 0
```

just make sure your cube_root returns integers for actual cubes. Complete solution as gist https://gist.github.com/tymofij/9035744

Answer (score 0):

```
int countNoOfCubes(int a, int b) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int startsCube = (int) Math.ceil(Math.cbrt(a)); Math.pow(
                startsCube, 3.0) <= b; startsCube++) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by @Tim is faster than the one provided by @Erick, especially when A...B range increased.
Let me quote the ground from github here: 
"one can notice that x³ > y³ for any x > y. (that is called monotonic function)
therefore for any x that lies in ∛A ≤ x ≤ ∛B, cube would fit: A ≤ x³ ≤ B

So to get number of cubes which lie within A..B, you can simply count number of integers between ∛A and ∛B. And number of integers between two numbers is their difference."

It seems perfectly correct, isn't it? It works for any power, not only for cube.
Here is my port of cube_root method for java:

```
/*
 * make sure your cube_root returns integers for actual cubes
 */
static double cubeRoot(int x) {
    //negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power
    double res = Math.copySign(Math.pow(Math.abs(x), (1.0d/3)) , x);
    long rounded_res = symmetricRound(res);
    if (rounded_res * rounded_res * rounded_res == x)
        return rounded_res;
    else
        return res;
}

private static long symmetricRound( double d ) {
    return d < 0 ? - Math.round( -d ) : Math.round( d );
}
```

I am aware of Math.cbrt in java but with Math.pow approach it is easy to generalize the solution for other exponents.

Comment: Please note that it does not really work for _all_ powers, only for odd ones (1,3,5..). For even powers (2,4,6) you can not just grab roots of borders and compute the difference, you have to account for negative numbers.

E.g. for a task of finding squares in the range of [-1...17] the numbers which fit would be [-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]